# Table header text disappears when hiding a column

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table inside of a wrapper. I need the column header to be static at the top when the user scrolls. I have that part working fine.

One of the other requirements is that columns can be shown or hidden, and the header should adjust. That seems to work with one minor bug: the header text is disappearing when the user has scrolled and then hits "hide column".

You can find the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/joelkinzel/j3RtD/1/

HTML:

```
<style type="text/css">
    body{
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
    }
    .tablewrapper {
        height: 400px;
        margin:0 auto;
        overflow: auto;
        position: relative;
        width: 75%;
    }
    table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        position: relative;
        width:100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    thead {
        background-color:#000;
        color:#fff;
        position: absolute;
        text-align: left;
        height:1.5em;
        top:0;
    }
    tbody > tr:first-child {
        border-top:1.5em solid transparent;
    }
</style>

    <h1> Floating Table Headers</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin eu cursus ligula. In non rutrum mauris. Donec aliquet, urna at dignissim scelerisque, nunc libero adipiscing ante, ac luctus mauris est id felis. Nunc vel sagittis arcu. Maecenas quam tortor, congue vestibulum dolor quis, tempor blandit libero. Aenean et magna et massa malesuada auctor. Nunc nec justo quis nisl lobortis mattis. Etiam non ipsum ac quam gravida porta. Sed vitae malesuada magna. Nulla sed urna sed purus sodales vestibulum.</p>

    <button class="show-column" type="button">Show Column</button>
    <button class="hide-column" type="button">Hide Column</button>
<div class="tablewrapper">
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Col 1</th>
            <th>Col 2</th>
            <th>Col 3</th>
            <th>Col 4</th>
            <th>Col 1</th>
            <th>Col 2</th>
            <th>Col 3</th>
            <th>Col 4</th>
            <th>Col 1</th>
            <th>Col 2</th>
            <th>Col 3</th>
            <th>Col 4</th>
            <th>Col 1</th>
            <th>Col 2</th>
            <th>Col 3</th>
            <th>Col 4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Uno</td>
            <td>Dos</td>
            <td>Tres</td>
            <td>Quatro</td>
            <td>Uno</td>
            <td>Dos</td>
            <td>Tres</td>
            <td>Quatro</td>
            <td>Uno</td>
            <td>Dos</td>
            <td>Tres</td>
            <td>Quatro</td>
            <td>Uno</td>
            <td>Dos</td>
            <td>Tres</td>
            <td>Quatro</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Ein</td>
            <td>Swei</td>
            <td>Drei</td>
            <td>Fier</td>
            <td>Ein</td>
            <td>Swei</td>
            <td>Drei</td>
            <td>Fier</td>
            <td>Ein</td>
            <td>Swei</td>
            <td>Drei</td>
            <td>Fier</td>
            <td>Ein</td>
            <td>Swei</td>
            <td>Drei</td>
            <td>Fier</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Uno</td>
            <td>Dos</td>
            <td>Tres</td>
            <td>Quatro</td>
            <td>Uno</td>
            <td>Dos</td>
            <td>Tres</td>
            <td>Quatro</td>
            <td>Uno</td>
            <td>Dos</td>
            <td>Tres</td>
            <td>Quatro</td>
            <td>Uno</td>
            <td>Dos</td>
            <td>Tres</td>
            <td>Quatro</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Ein</td>
            <td>Swei</td>
            <td>Drei</td>
            <td>Fier</td>
            <td>Ein</td>
            <td>Swei</td>
            <td>Drei</td>
            <td>Fier</td>
            <td>Ein</td>
            <td>Swei</td>
            <td>Drei</td>
            <td>Fier</td>
            <td>Ein</td>
            <td>Swei</td>
            <td>Drei</td>
            <td>Fier</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Uno</td>
            <td>Dos</td>
            <td>Tres</td>
            <td>Quatro</td>
            <td>Uno</td>
            <td>Dos</td>
            <td>Tres</td>
            <td>Quatro</td>
            <td>Uno</td>
            <td>Dos</td>
            <td>Tres</td>
            <td>Quatro</td>
            <td>Uno</td>
            <td>Dos</td>
            <td>Tres</td>
            <td>Quatro</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Ein</td>
            <td>Swei</td>
            <td>Drei</td>
            <td>Fier</td>
            <td>Ein</td>
            <td>Swei</td>
            <td>Drei</td>
            <td>Fier</td>
            <td>Ein</td>
            <td>Swei</td>
            <td>Drei</td>
            <td>Fier</td>
            <td>Ein</td>
            <td>Swei</td>
            <td>Drei</td>
            <td>Fier</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Uno</td>
            <td>Dos</td>
            <td>Tres</td>
            <td>Quatro</td>
            <td>Uno</td>
            <td>Dos</td>
            <td>Tres</td>
            <td>Quatro</td>
            <td>Uno</td>
            <td>Dos</td>
            <td>Tres</td>
            <td>Quatro</td>
            <td>Uno</td>
            <td>Dos</td>
            <td>Tres</td>
            <td>Quatro</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Ein</td>
            <td>Swei</td>
            <td>Drei</td>
            <td>Fier</td>
            <td>Ein</td>
            <td>Swei</td>
            <td>Drei</td>
            <td>Fier</td>
            <td>Ein</td>
            <td>Swei</td>
            <td>Drei</td>
            <td>Fier</td>
            <td>Ein</td>
            <td>Swei</td>
            <td>Drei</td>
            <td>Fier</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Uno</td>
            <td>Dos</td>
            <td>Tres</td>
            <td>Quatro</td>
            <td>Uno</td>
            <td>Dos</td>
            <td>Tres</td>
            <td>Quatro</td>
            <td>Uno</td>
            <td>Dos</td>
            <td>Tres</td>
            <td>Quatro</td>
            <td>Uno</td>
            <td>Dos</td>
            <td>Tres</td>
            <td>Quatro</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Ein</td>
            <td>Swei</td>
            <td>Drei</td>
            <td>Fier</td>
            <td>Ein</td>
            <td>Swei</td>
            <td>Drei</td>
            <td>Fier</td>
            <td>Ein</td>
            <td>Swei</td>
            <td>Drei</td>
            <td>Fier</td>
            <td>Ein</td>
            <td>Swei</td>
            <td>Drei</td>
            <td>Fier</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Uno</td>
            <td>Dos</td>
            <td>Tres</td>
            <td>Quatro</td>
            <td>Uno</td>
            <td>Dos</td>
            <td>Tres</td>
            <td>Quatro</td>
            <td>Uno</td>
            <td>Dos</td>
            <td>Tres</td>
            <td>Quatro</td>
            <td>Uno</td>
            <td>Dos</td>
            <td>Tres</td>
            <td>Quatro</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Ein</td>
            <td>Swei</td>
            <td>Drei</td>
            <td>Fier</td>
            <td>Ein</td>
            <td>Swei</td>
            <td>Drei</td>
            <td>Fier</td>
            <td>Ein</td>
            <td>Swei</td>
            <td>Drei</td>
            <td>Fier</td>
            <td>Ein</td>
            <td>Swei</td>
            <td>Drei</td>
            <td>Fier</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Uno</td>
            <td>Dos</td>
            <td>Tres</td>
            <td>Quatro</td>
            <td>Uno</td>
            <td>Dos</td>
            <td>Tres</td>
            <td>Quatro</td>
            <td>Uno</td>
            <td>Dos</td>
            <td>Tres</td>
            <td>Quatro</td>
            <td>Uno</td>
            <td>Dos</td>
            <td>Tres</td>
            <td>Quatro</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Ein</td>
            <td>Swei</td>
            <td>Drei</td>
            <td>Fier</td>
            <td>Ein</td>
            <td>Swei</td>
            <td>Drei</td>
            <td>Fier</td>
            <td>Ein</td>
            <td>Swei</td>
            <td>Drei</td>
            <td>Fier</td>
            <td>Ein</td>
            <td>Swei</td>
            <td>Drei</td>
            <td>Fier</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Uno</td>
            <td>Dos</td>
            <td>Tres</td>
            <td>Quatro</td>
            <td>Uno</td>
            <td>Dos</td>
            <td>Tres</td>
            <td>Quatro</td>
            <td>Uno</td>
            <td>Dos</td>
            <td>Tres</td>
            <td>Quatro</td>
            <td>Uno</td>
            <td>Dos</td>
            <td>Tres</td>
            <td>Quatro</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Ein</td>
            <td>Swei</td>
            <td>Drei</td>
            <td>Fier</td>
            <td>Ein</td>
            <td>Swei</td>
            <td>Drei</td>
            <td>Fier</td>
            <td>Ein</td>
            <td>Swei</td>
            <td>Drei</td>
            <td>Fier</td>
            <td>Ein</td>
            <td>Swei</td>
            <td>Drei</td>
            <td>Fier</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Uno</td>
            <td>Dos</td>
            <td>Tres</td>
            <td>Quatro</td>
            <td>Uno</td>
            <td>Dos</td>
            <td>Tres</td>
            <td>Quatro</td>
            <td>Uno</td>
            <td>Dos</td>
            <td>Tres</td>
            <td>Quatro</td>
            <td>Uno</td>
            <td>Dos</td>
            <td>Tres</td>
            <td>Quatro</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Ein</td>
            <td>Swei</td>
            <td>Drei</td>
            <td>Fier</td>
            <td>Ein</td>
            <td>Swei</td>
            <td>Drei</td>
            <td>Fier</td>
            <td>Ein</td>
            <td>Swei</td>
            <td>Drei</td>
            <td>Fier</td>
            <td>Ein</td>
            <td>Swei</td>
            <td>Drei</td>
            <td>Fier</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Uno</td>
            <td>Dos</td>
            <td>Tres</td>
            <td>Quatro</td>
            <td>Uno</td>
            <td>Dos</td>
            <td>Tres</td>
            <td>Quatro</td>
            <td>Uno</td>
            <td>Dos</td>
            <td>Tres</td>
            <td>Quatro</td>
            <td>Uno</td>
            <td>Dos</td>
            <td>Tres</td>
            <td>Quatro</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Ein</td>
            <td>Swei</td>
            <td>Drei</td>
            <td>Fier</td>
            <td>Ein</td>
            <td>Swei</td>
            <td>Drei</td>
            <td>Fier</td>
            <td>Ein</td>
            <td>Swei</td>
            <td>Drei</td>
            <td>Fier</td>
            <td>Ein</td>
            <td>Swei</td>
            <td>Drei</td>
            <td>Fier</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Uno</td>
            <td>Dos</td>
            <td>Tres</td>
            <td>Quatro</td>
            <td>Uno</td>
            <td>Dos</td>
            <td>Tres</td>
            <td>Quatro</td>
            <td>Uno</td>
            <td>Dos</td>
            <td>Tres</td>
            <td>Quatro</td>
            <td>Uno</td>
            <td>Dos</td>
            <td>Tres</td>
            <td>Quatro</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Ein</td>
            <td>Swei</td>
            <td>Drei</td>
            <td>Fier</td>
            <td>Ein</td>
            <td>Swei</td>
            <td>Drei</td>
            <td>Fier</td>
            <td>Ein</td>
            <td>Swei</td>
            <td>Drei</td>
            <td>Fier</td>
            <td>Ein</td>
            <td>Swei</td>
            <td>Drei</td>
            <td>Fier</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Uno</td>
            <td>Dos</td>
            <td>Tres</td>
            <td>Quatro</td>
            <td>Uno</td>
            <td>Dos</td>
            <td>Tres</td>
            <td>Quatro</td>
            <td>Uno</td>
            <td>Dos</td>
            <td>Tres</td>
            <td>Quatro</td>
            <td>Uno</td>
            <td>Dos</td>
            <td>Tres</td>
            <td>Quatro</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Ein</td>
            <td>Swei</td>
            <td>Drei</td>
            <td>Fier</td>
            <td>Ein</td>
            <td>Swei</td>
            <td>Drei</td>
            <td>Fier</td>
            <td>Ein</td>
            <td>Swei</td>
            <td>Drei</td>
            <td>Fier</td>
            <td>Ein</td>
            <td>Swei</td>
            <td>Drei</td>
            <td>Fier</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Uno</td>
            <td>Dos</td>
            <td>Tres</td>
            <td>Quatro</td>
            <td>Uno</td>
            <td>Dos</td>
            <td>Tres</td>
            <td>Quatro</td>
            <td>Uno</td>
            <td>Dos</td>
            <td>Tres</td>
            <td>Quatro</td>
            <td>Uno</td>
            <td>Dos</td>
            <td>Tres</td>
            <td>Quatro</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Ein</td>
            <td>Swei</td>
            <td>Drei</td>
            <td>Fier</td>
            <td>Ein</td>
            <td>Swei</td>
            <td>Drei</td>
            <td>Fier</td>
            <td>Ein</td>
            <td>Swei</td>
            <td>Drei</td>
            <td>Fier</td>
            <td>Ein</td>
            <td>Swei</td>
            <td>Drei</td>
            <td>Fier</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Uno</td>
            <td>Dos</td>
            <td>Tres</td>
            <td>Quatro</td>
            <td>Uno</td>
            <td>Dos</td>
            <td>Tres</td>
            <td>Quatro</td>
            <td>Uno</td>
            <td>Dos</td>
            <td>Tres</td>
            <td>Quatro</td>
            <td>Uno</td>
            <td>Dos</td>
            <td>Tres</td>
            <td>Quatro</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Ein</td>
            <td>Swei</td>
            <td>Drei</td>
            <td>Fier</td>
            <td>Ein</td>
            <td>Swei</td>
            <td>Drei</td>
            <td>Fier</td>
            <td>Ein</td>
            <td>Swei</td>
            <td>Drei</td>
            <td>Fier</td>
            <td>Ein</td>
            <td>Swei</td>
            <td>Drei</td>
            <td>Fier</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Uno</td>
            <td>Dos</td>
            <td>Tres</td>
            <td>Quatro</td>
            <td>Uno</td>
            <td>Dos</td>
            <td>Tres</td>
            <td>Quatro</td>
            <td>Uno</td>
            <td>Dos</td>
            <td>Tres</td>
            <td>Quatro</td>
            <td>Uno</td>
            <td>Dos</td>
            <td>Tres</td>
            <td>Quatro</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Ein</td>
            <td>Swei</td>
            <td>Drei</td>
            <td>Fier</td>
            <td>Ein</td>
            <td>Swei</td>
            <td>Drei</td>
            <td>Fier</td>
            <td>Ein</td>
            <td>Swei</td>
            <td>Drei</td>
            <td>Fier</td>
            <td>Ein</td>
            <td>Swei</td>
            <td>Drei</td>
            <td>Fier</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Uno</td>
            <td>Dos</td>
            <td>Tres</td>
            <td>Quatro</td>
            <td>Uno</td>
            <td>Dos</td>
            <td>Tres</td>
            <td>Quatro</td>
            <td>Uno</td>
            <td>Dos</td>
            <td>Tres</td>
            <td>Quatro</td>
            <td>Uno</td>
            <td>Dos</td>
            <td>Tres</td>
            <td>Quatro</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Ein</td>
            <td>Swei</td>
            <td>Drei</td>
            <td>Fier</td>
            <td>Ein</td>
            <td>Swei</td>
            <td>Drei</td>
            <td>Fier</td>
            <td>Ein</td>
            <td>Swei</td>
            <td>Drei</td>
            <td>Fier</td>
            <td>Ein</td>
            <td>Swei</td>
            <td>Drei</td>
            <td>Fier</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Uno</td>
            <td>Dos</td>
            <td>Tres</td>
            <td>Quatro</td>
            <td>Uno</td>
            <td>Dos</td>
            <td>Tres</td>
            <td>Quatro</td>
            <td>Uno</td>
            <td>Dos</td>
            <td>Tres</td>
            <td>Quatro</td>
            <td>Uno</td>
            <td>Dos</td>
            <td>Tres</td>
            <td>Quatro</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Ein</td>
            <td>Swei</td>
            <td>Drei</td>
            <td>Fier</td>
            <td>Ein</td>
            <td>Swei</td>
            <td>Drei</td>
            <td>Fier</td>
            <td>Ein</td>
            <td>Swei</td>
            <td>Drei</td>
            <td>Fier</td>
            <td>Ein</td>
            <td>Swei</td>
            <td>Drei</td>
            <td>Fier</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Uno</td>
            <td>Dos</td>
            <td>Tres</td>
            <td>Quatro</td>
            <td>Uno</td>
            <td>Dos</td>
            <td>Tres</td>
            <td>Quatro</td>
            <td>Uno</td>
            <td>Dos</td>
            <td>Tres</td>
            <td>Quatro</td>
            <td>Uno</td>
            <td>Dos</td>
            <td>Tres</td>
            <td>Quatro</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Ein</td>
            <td>Swei</td>
            <td>Drei</td>
            <td>Fier</td>
            <td>Ein</td>
            <td>Swei</td>
            <td>Drei</td>
            <td>Fier</td>
            <td>Ein</td>
            <td>Swei</td>
            <td>Drei</td>
            <td>Fier</td>
            <td>Ein</td>
            <td>Swei</td>
            <td>Drei</td>
            <td>Fier</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function(){
    var tableWrapperScollPos = 0;
    var tableWrapperOffset = $('.tablewrapper').offset().top;
    sizeTableHeader();
    $(window).on('resize', function(){
        tableWrapperOffset = $('.tablewrapper').offset().top;
        sizeTableHeader();
        positionTableHeader();
    });
    $('.tablewrapper').on('scroll', function(){
        tableWrapperScollPos = $(this).scrollTop();
        sizeTableHeader();
        positionTableHeader();
    });

    function positionTableHeader(){
        if (tableWrapperScollPos > 0){
            $('thead').css({
                'position': 'fixed',
                'top': tableWrapperOffset
            });
        } else {
            $('thead').css({
                'position': 'absolute',
                'top': 0
            });
        }
    }

    function sizeTableHeader(){
        var columns = $('table tr:first-child > td');
        var headers = $('table thead th');
        var tableWidth = $('thead').parent().width();
        var columnWidths = [];

        $.each(columns, function(index){
            $(headers[index]).css('width', $(this).width());
        });
        $('thead').width(tableWidth);
    }

    $('.show-column').on('click', function(){
        $('table td:nth-child(4),table th:nth-child(4)').show();
        sizeTableHeader();
    });
    $('.hide-column').on('click', function(){
        $('table td:nth-child(4), table th:nth-child(4)').hide();
        sizeTableHeader();
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works with me without problems in IE but chrome have the issue you mentioned

I tried to add a class to tr in thead having position:absolute and it works

```
.head {
    position: absolute;
}
```

and add it to tr in thead

```
<thead>
    <tr class="head">
        <th>Col 1</th>
        <th>Col 2</th>
        <th>Col 3</th>
        <th>Col 4</th>
        <th>Col 1</th>
        <th>Col 2</th>
        <th>Col 3</th>
        <th>Col 4</th>
        <th>Col 1</th>
        <th>Col 2</th>
        <th>Col 3</th>
        <th>Col 4</th>
        <th>Col 1</th>
        <th>Col 2</th>
        <th>Col 3</th>
        <th>Col 4</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bmwz9/E42tA/)

Comment: Thanks! Accepted as the answer, if anyone knows the technical reason behind what is going on here, I'd be interested to hear as well.